# Почему startOfMonth() не работает если после него идет endOfMonth() в Carbon?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, carbon

Если $date - это текущая дата, то при выводе данных получаю две идентичные строки, которые соответсвтуют концу месяца. А должна первая запись соответствовать началу месяца. Что здесь не так?

```
$start = $date->startOfMonth();
$end = $date->endOfMonth();
dd($start, $end);
```

Выводится:

```
Carbon @1535759999 {#318 ▼
   date: 2018-08-31 23:59:59.949635 UTC (+00:00)
}
Carbon @1535759999 {#318 ▼
   date: 2018-08-31 23:59:59.949635 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, и оно будет выглядеть так:

```
$start = $date->startOfMonth();
$end = $date->copy()->endOfMonth();
dd($start, $end);
```

Либо нужно создать два обьекта $date:

```
$start = $date1->startOfMonth();
$end = $date2->endOfMonth();
dd($start, $end);
```